# VirtualBox showing blank black screen when I try to run Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to set up a VM with VirtualBox to run Ubuntu 18.04.2. Everything set up just fine, but when I start it up, it doesn't show the Ubuntu installer, only a black screen with a flashing cursor in the upper left corner. It doesn't respond to any keyboard commands and doesn't do anything. I'm super new to all this and have no idea what I'm doing, and I need to have this set up for a class so I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit your question and add the new information **up there**. Which GPU (graphics card/chip) is the VM emulating? If it is using the same GPU as the host, please add that in the question.

Comment: In addition, what version of VirtualBox are you using and is your host system Windows or unix based?

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox 6.0.4 and my host system is Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

1. Virtualisation needs to be enabled in BIOS.
2. Hyper-V must be un-checked under: Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows Features on or off.
3. You may also need to edit the following registry key (should be set to 0): HKLM|SYSTEM|CurrentControlSet|Control|DeviceGuard|EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity|Enabled
4. PC will need a reboot for above changes to take effect.